# Validating input with try-catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I am trying to learn try-catch uses and have to validate input so that the user must enter 1 or 2 for the program to continue. I believe I am close, but cannot seem to get the program to continue if the user enters something wrong such as '3' or '2.12'.

Here's what I have:

```
String input = " ";

try {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = scan.next();

        Integer.parseInt(input);

        if (!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Invalid imput! Please select '1' or '2':");
        }

    } catch (InputMismatchException a) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Invalid imput! Please select '1' or '2':");

    }
```

Comment: `if (!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) { throw new InputMismatchException ();`

Comment: You throw InputMismatchException  when the input from the scanner is different from the expected type(not value). Throwing InputMismatchException for your scnerio is quite abusing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't necessarily see the point of using `InputMismatchException` for your use case.  Instead, if the input doesn't match what you expect, you can log an error and just prompt the user to input again.

But `[Integer#parseInt()][1]` *can* throw an exception if the input isn't an actual integer.  In your original code you never actually use the result of this call, but I have done so in my answer.  In this case, it does potentially make sense to use a try-catch block.

```
int result;
while (true) {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = scan.next();
        result = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not parse input, please try again.");
        continue;
    }

    if (result != 1 && result != 2) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Please select '1' or '2':");
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put in your condition the throw statement in able to your catch statement fetch the error, the code should be like this:

```
String input = " ";

try {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = scan.next();

    Integer.parseInt(input);

    if (!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Invalid imput! Please select '1' or '2':");
        throw new InputMismatchException ();
    }

} catch (InputMismatchException a) {

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Invalid imput! Please select '1' or '2':");


}
```

Comment: This helps, but it does not keep the program running?

Comment: Try to add (input = scan.next();) after     System.out.println("Invalid imput! Please select '1' or '2':");
in the catch statement

Answer (score 0):

The code is expecting for positive integers but can input string and loop again until got a positive integer input value.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Integer expectedOutput = -1;

public Integer getInputNumber(){

    boolean valid;
    String inputData;

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Input Number: \t");
        try {
            inputData = scanner.nextLine();
            // expecting positive integers
            if (Integer.parseInt(inputData) > 0) {
                expectedOutput = Integer.parseInt(inputData);
                valid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
                valid = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            valid = false;
        }
    } while(!valid);
    return expectedOutput;}
```